# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest in order to reduce the server load

Tags: html, performance, user-experience

I want to raise a discussion here.

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest are deprecated for obvious reasons, having the user wait for an operation may result in a worse user experience.

However, imagine I have a webpage that has a series of modal windows, one of which is a, for example, configuration modal.
The most common use case will be that the user loads the page but never actually wants to configure anything via the configuration popup.

Asking the server for all the elements, including the contents of said modal could result in longer overall response time and load to the server.
Imagine that the configuration modal has loads of high-resolution images (kind of unlikely if it is a configuration modal but whatever).

Is it really inadvisable to load the contents of the modal whenever the user requests it via `$.load`?

You could put a spinner while the user waits or something, I don't think it is that detrimental.

What do you guys think? Maybe this has already been discussed plenty of times, sorry if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Since the page is single-threaded, it really is a bad idea. The whole page will block until the call completes. As for server load, it's really not a problem. HTTP is **designed** for the rapid delivery of static content.

Comment: It's not really that fast tho, maybe a single HTML document loads in milliseconds, but some content, like images, may take a longer time. In the example I said, that modal could have hundreds or thousands of images, why should I load all of them if the user is most-likely not even going to  open the modal?

Comment: By the way, I'm not talking about blocking the whole thread, since that would render the UI unusable, I'm talking about calling $("#someID").load("someUrl") with a callback function. Does that block the whole thread?